# Use mapN to apply values

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I have the following code snippet:

```
final case class Configuration(env: Env, user: String, password: String, address: String)

trait DbSetup[F[_]] {

  type EnvT[A] = OptionT[F, A]

  def system: EnvT[Env]

  def user: EnvT[String]

  def password: EnvT[String]

  def address: EnvT[String]

}

object DbSetup {

  def get[F[_] : Monad](s: DbSetup[F]): s.EnvT[Configuration] = ???

}
```

How to use [Applicative](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/applicative.html) function `mapN` in the implementation of `get` function to get `Configuration` filled?

Comment: What did you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
import cats.syntax.apply._

def get[F[_] : Monad](s: DbSetup[F]): s.EnvT[Configuration] = 
  (s.system, s.user, s.password, s.address).mapN(Configuration)
```

May I recommend you to read [Herding Cats](http://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/) or [Scala with Cats](https://www.scalawithcats.com/)?

Comment: Since it only requires `mapN`, it may be good to only ask for **Applicative** instead of **Monad**.